# string assignment with or operator

Tags: string

I am trying something like this

```
String test = " "

if ( condition == true )

{

 test = "value1" or "value2";

}
```

if the condition is true, I am trying to assign one of the two values to test,  can someone help on this.

Thanks

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Java? C#? what language do you use?

Comment: Thanks all for quick look, using java above

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. You can only have one string assigned to your variable test, not sure what the or is supposed to be representing.

Comment: If my "if" condition is satisfied, the expected values of my string can be either value1 or value2

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this,

`test = (condition)?"somevalue":"somevalue"`

Basically, I am  using ternary operators. If the condition is true, then the value after '**?**' gets assigned to test. Otherwise, test will equal to the value after '**:**'. :)

Comment: if i have two values value1 and value2, can i do like this with your syntax - test = (condition)?"value1":"value2"

Comment: Yes, that is correct. ;)

Comment: I am validating the string "test" here, so if my condition is true, then "test" can be either of them

Comment: Any specific reason for accepting this answer ? I answered you first & also provided you 2 solutions and code as well. @user2505867

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
test = (condition)?"somevalue":"SOMEVALUE";
```

If `condition` is true then `somevalue` is assigned (that's after ? ) - if false, then `SOMEVALUE` is assigned (that's after : )

**BUT**, this is not assigning BOTH values. You **cannot** assign 2 values to a variable *at the same time*.

You can also generate random number like 0 or 1 - and based on result you can assign value to `test`. Like in `c` you can do this as:

```cs
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

srand(time(NULL));
int random = rand() % 2;   //this will assign either 1 or 0 to random

if (random == 0)     //if number generated is 0, test will be assigned value1
   test = "value1";

if (random == 1)
   test = "value2";    //if number generated is 1, test will be assigned value2
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to assign 2 values to a variable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could do:

```
string test = "";

if(condition == true)
{
    test = "some value";
}
else
{
    test = "some other value";
}
```

Or more compact (using [implicit type declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) and the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
var test = (condition) ? "some value" : "some other value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot assign two value to a single variable.
 
However, you can assign randomly **one of the two values**.

If that's what you meant, you could do this:

```
String test = " "

if ( condition == true )
{
    if ( getRandomBoolean() ) {
        test = "value1";
    }
    else {
        test = "value2";
    }
}

public boolean getRandomBoolean() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextBoolean();
}
```

Comment: I am randomly assign one of the two values, I am using java here

Comment: This should do the trick.

Comment: Btw you should edit your question and write `one of the two values` instead of `two values`.

Comment: Did you try my solution?